# Angular Server Side Rendering returning error [object Object]

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

I was trying to implement server side rendering with angular-universal in our existing application using the following guide:

https://angular.io/guide/universal

First I fixed some known issues which caused errors:

- Used absolute urls for http-requests everywhere
- Made browser modules conditional (Window)

But when running "npm run dev:ssr" and after loading the website, I still get the following error:

Chart not defined (guessing this is a universal build, and I don't know why this happens -- Aviad)
[object Object]

Unfortunately I don't get any stack trace or info why this happens. Did anyone have the same issue and knows the cause or how I could analyze this further?

Comment: Do you use any chart component? It's probably because you (or one of your modules) includes a chart lib which does not support SSR

Comment: Yes indeed it's the ng2-charts component. I removed it completely but not I just get the error [object Object] with no futher information.